# Linq observable collection cast error

Tags: c#, linq

EDIT: BELOW CODE WORKS! (I commented out, built, and later uncommented and it worked).

I have an `ObservableCollection` for a `ListBox`. I want to select some of those items based on display name only, as I wont know item value. However I get a casting error (IEnumerable to ObservableCollection).

```c#
ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem> unselectedcollection
    = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem>
        (dt.AsEnumerable()
           .Select(i => new ListBoxItem(i[ColumnNames.LISTNAMECOL].ToString(),
                                        i[ColumnNames.LISTVALUECOL].ToString())));

ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem> selectedcollection
    = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem>
        (from item in unselectedcollection.AsEnumerable()
         where (item.Name == "firstName"
                || item.Name == "secondName"
                || item.Name == "thirdName")
         select item);
```

I have tried the various casting options I could think of. What am I missing?

Comment: Include your first collection (`unselectedcollection`) too, it's probably the source of the problem.

Comment: What is unselectedcollection's type?

Comment: I have added it to original question now

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

One common issue I've run into when dealing with Collections and passing a Linq result into them is the collection is not enumerated and enumerating it through a call to ToList often fixes the issue. I would give that a go and see if it helps.

```
ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem> selectedcollection
  = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItem>(
      unselectedcollection.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(item => item.Name == "firstName"
                                         || item.Name == "secondName"
                                         || item.Name == "thirdName")
                          .ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain how or why, but I commented out this section, filled it with blank lists to keep testing. I just came back and uncommented it to give exact error message (as requested by @nakiya) and rebuilt...

...and it worked.

Again I don't know how or why but at least I can move on.